# ARFF parsing in ELKI 0.6.5 or 0.6.0

Tags: arff, elki

I would like to use the newest version of ELKI, but I get errors leading to nullpointerexeptions and that task fails. When using 0.6.0 it works fine.

Here is some toy arff-data:

```
@ATTRIBUTE 'var_0032' real
@ATTRIBUTE 'id' real
@ATTRIBUTE 'outlier' {'no','yes'}

@DATA
0.185185185185,1.0,'no'
0.0740740740741,2.0,'no'
```

But I get the failure in 0.6.5:

```
Invalid quoted line in input: no closing quote found in: @ATTRIBUTE 'outlier' {'no','yes'}
Task failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.VisualizerContext.processNewResult(VisualizerContext.java:300)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.VisualizerContext.<init>(VisualizerContext.java:141)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.VisualizerParameterizer.newContext(VisualizerParameterizer.java:193)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.gui.ResultVisualizer.processNewResult(ResultVisualizer.java:116)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.OutputStep.runResultHandlers(OutputStep.java:70)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask.run(KDDTask.java:120)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication.run(KDDCLIApplication.java:60)
    at [...]
```

In the 0.6.0 this just seems to be a warning:
`Invalid quoted line in input: no closing quote found in: @ATTRIBUTE 'outlier' {'no','yes'}` it still produces the ROCCURVE.

Should I be worried?
Should I change my arff file, and how?

Comment: I am a bit concerned with 0.6.5, does it work well enough even though it is not a stable version? Or is it me who sets ELKIs dropdown menus wrong. I only fiddle with inputfile, algorithm, parameter, evaluator=ROCAUCCurve and rocauc.positive. 
Are there settings I miss to get a ROCAUC curve.

When datasets get large it is probably normal to add an index, how big?

Wonder if this is why my ROCAUC values are pretty low sometimes, 0.4, but still sometimes they are higher like 0.8

Comment: 0.6.5 works fine for me, but I use the git version now.

Answer (score 0):

The ARFF file format (https://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28developer+version%29) doesn't use quotes there.

```
@RELATION example
@ATTRIBUTE var_0032 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE id NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE outlier {no,yes}

@DATA
0.185185185185,1.0,no
0.0740740740741,2.0,no
```

also, if your `id` column is really an id, don't give it `real` (which is only an alias for `numeric`) datatype. It's not a numerical column, and if you aren't careful it may be misused in the analysis.

So maybe better use something like this:

```
@RELATION example
@ATTRIBUTE var_0032 NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE id STRING
@ATTRIBUTE class {no,yes}

@DATA
0.185185185185,'1',no
0.0740740740741,'2',no
```

to get a proper ARFF file. I havn't tested, does this work better?

Comment: It goes better with your idea, if I take AutomaticEvaluation, instead of ROCAUCCurve. Now I have to change my data automatically. I dont get though why I have to set the bubble plot with top k, when I am not interested in seeing that.

Comment: org.apache.batik.bridge.BridgeException: null:-1
The attribute "d" of the element <path> is invalid at .... 

Except I get a BridgeException.

I will try out the Git version too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **definitely use 0.6.5**. ELKI is not at a 1.0 release yet, there are bugs. They will not be fixed in old versions, only in the new version, because we still *need* to be able to do larger API changes. Essentially, there should be **no reason to use anything but the latest version**. ELKI 0.7 will appear end of August at VLDB 2015.

ARFF is not used a lot. There may be errors in the parser, and ARFF support for categorial data is very very limited right now. The strengths of the ARFF format are when you have lots of categorial attributes, but that is mostly used in classification - and ELKI doesn't include much classification algorithms yet (since Weka is a strong tool for that already, we focus on algorithms that are not available/good in Weka).

Batik errors like this are usually due to NaN or infinite values. There are still some errors in the visualization code because SVG doesn't give good type safety, unfortunately. You can easily build SVG documents that are invalid, or that contain invalid characters such as `∞` in some coordinate, and then the Batik renderer will fail with such an error message.

What are you exactly trying to do? It looks a bit as if you are trying to compute the ROC curve for the existing output of an algorithm? I don't think there is an easy way to read an ARFF file containing (score, id, label) rows and compute a ROC curve using the MiniGUI. It's not hard to do in Java code, but it's not a use case of the KDD process workflow of the UI.

Comment: I got data (norm, nonduplicates, outlier-label) to fit to outlierdetection. I want to see for which values of k LOF perform well, so I ran many datasets with varying k(in 0.6.0) (but maybe that's stupid since k is dependent on the dataset)
After finding a good k,I would start to build synthetic datasets,like the dense-sparse problem to check how LOF finds the local outliers and DBoutlier don't.This I guess I could see in LOC having a larger AUCROC value
In reality I want to test LOF LDOF and DBoutlier's results and draw parallels between them. I have to make my own synthetic data sets for that

Comment: Is the resulting ROCAUC from running an arff file in the gui then wrong and unusable?
At least I get the same results from 0.6.5 and the git version.
But a better way should be by invoking it from java? Because of the calculation precision?

Comment: Depends on what you are trying to do. If you run LOF etc. *inside* ELKI, its fine. If you want to *read* a result you computed *outside* of ELKI, you probably need to use Java code. What you shared above (with the `id` column) looked incorrect.